# htaccess in subfolder on subdomain in DirectAdmin causes 403

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

First of all: I noticed a lot of topics on similar issues and I've read quiet a bunch of them. However non seem to be of the exact same nature as the error I'm having.

Within my DirectAdmin panel I've created a subdomain called `projects`, DirectAdmin automatically generates the structure on the FTP, the subdomain resolves to the folder `public_html/projects/`. Within this folder I'm planning on having folders per client to add their projects.

Let's kick of with an example:

1. Client called 'johnson'
2. Project called 'cars'
3. In this folder there is an index.html file
4. The htaccess file is within this project folder (cars)

The domain to this project is `http://projects.mydomain.com/johnson/cars/` and the internal structure is `public_html/projects/johnson/cars/`. Without a htaccess file everything works perfect, the index.html is opened automatically.

Now comes the part that is causing the issues. I'm using htaccess to rewrite URLs which used to work without any problems on the www. subdomain, but since I'm working in the projects folder it's causing 403 errors.

What I'd expect to work was:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options -Indexes

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /johson/cars/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ test.php?vars=$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

test.php is nothing much, just a file that `var_dump()`'s the $_GET variables. But instead of this page the 403 error shows up.

I tried a ton of things, such as:

1. RewriteBase /cars/
2. RewriteBase /projects/johnson/cars/
3. RewriteBase /projects/
4. RewriteBase /johnson/ (pretty much every thinkable variation)
5. RewriteBase /
6. Added `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^projects\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]` in front of the RewriteRules

But nothing seems to help.. I'm kind of stuck and I am clueless where to look. I've tried different searches on here and on Google. Perhaps I'm using the wrong keywords, but I can't find a similar probler and I've been trying to incorporate sollutions to other problems to mine without any success.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What are the rules in your main htaccess (for `www` subdomain) ? Also, i don't know if it's a typo error here but your `RewriteBase` contains `johson` and not `johnson`

Comment: The rewritebase is a typo :) The root contains a similar htaccess file. But even if this one is disabled the error remains the same.

Comment: Since you're getting a 403, did you apply enough privilege on your `projects` folder (and everything into it) ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Could not reproduce your problem locally. Please check your access log for error messages related to the 403 page you're seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar problem in the past. After about a week of fruitless trying to get it to work I found out that both .htaccess files were interfering with each other. What I did is make the subdomain a seperate domain under the same clientname in directadmin

Comment: I've already tried disabling the root htaccess without any success

Comment: I added the subdomain `projects.domain.com` as a domainname and followed on from there. Although I can't wrap my mind around what went wrong before, this situation seems to give me the posibility to continue! Thanks.

Comment: It works properly. The thing I noticed afterwards was a missing `Allow From All`. Adding this line made all pieces fall into place. Thanks again.

Comment: I just did a test and copied the subdomain to projects2.domain.com and tried again by adding a subdomain using DirectAdmin. Copied all files from projects2 to the projects folder within the domain root's public_html folder.... and... it works! I guess `Allow From All` was messing around. So both methods work.. +200 for pushing me in the right direction (the logs), that was the key to finding the solution.

Answer (score -1):

I redirected my subdomain to another link by creating a .htaccess file in the related folder, with the content:

```
Redirect / http://yourlink
```